# Unable to load class groovy.sql.Sql

Tags: stored-procedures, groovy

I'm trying to call an Oracle stored procedure from a groovy script and I'm getting the error which is in the title.

Here is my script:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
import java.util.logging.*

Logger.getLogger('groovy.sql').level = Level.ALL

def dbUser = 'YOU'
def dbPassword = 'WILL'
def dbDriver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
def dbURL = 'NEVER:KNOW'  

def query = Sql.newInstance(dbURL, dbUser, dbPassword, dbDriver)

def affiliateNumber = 18
def depositIdentifier = 55
def depositType = "00"
def depositAmount = 18.49
def depositCommunication = 135453
def d = new Date()
def depositDate = d.toTimestamp()
def criterium = 0

/*
sql.query('SELECT NO_AFF, DEN from AFF WHERE no_AFF = 4'){ resultSet ->
    while(resultSet.next()){
        println resultSet.getString('no_aff') + resultSet.getString('den')
    }
}
*/

query.call("CALL PAC_GCA_IMP_AUTO_2.IMP_AUTO(${affiliateNumber}, ${depositIdentifier}, ${depositType}, ${depositAmount}, ${depositCommunication}, ${depositDate}, ${criterium}, ?, ? )", [Sql.INTEGER, Sql.VARCHAR])
```

The commented sql query works fine but when I try to call my procedure I'm getting this stack trace :

> Information:Groovyc: While compiling
>   unit-tests-groovy:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class
>   groovy.sql.Sql due to missing dependency java/sql/SQLException    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:397)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:280)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1009)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getUnresolvedSuperClass(ClassNode.java:1004)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getSuperClass(ClassNode.java:998)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformPropertyExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:852)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:696)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ListExpression.transformExpression(ListExpression.java:68)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:711)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.Expression.transformExpressions(Expression.java:51)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression.transformExpression(ArgumentListExpression.java:69)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:711)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transformMethodCallExpression(ResolveVisitor.java:1079)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.transform(ResolveVisitor.java:702)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitExpressionStatement(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:142)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.CodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(CodeVisitorSupport.java:37)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitBlockStatement(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:166)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitBlockStatement(ResolveVisitor.java:1336)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:71)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:104)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:115)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeExpressionTransformer.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitConstructorOrMethod(ResolveVisitor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:126)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1081)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1279)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:176)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$12.call(CompilationUnit.java:663)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:554)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovyCompilerWrapper.compile(GroovyCompilerWrapper.java:62)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.DependentGroovycRunner.runGroovyc(DependentGroovycRunner.java:115)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.jetbrains.groovy.compiler.rt.GroovycRunner.intMain2(GroovycRunner.java:136)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.runGroovycInThisProcess(InProcessGroovyc.java:158)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.groovy.InProcessGroovyc.lambda$runGroovyc$0(InProcessGroovyc.java:88)
>     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>     at
>   java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

The script is compiled when I remove `[Sql.INTEGER, Sql.VARCHAR]` (They are OUT parameters) parameters So I think that there is something wrong with them...

I've found a solution to make my procedure work :

```
def returnCode = query.call("DECLARE v_sqlcode PLS_INTEGER; v_sqlerrm VARCHAR2(500); BEGIN PAC_GCA_IMP_AUTO_2.IMP_AUTO(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, v_sqlcode, v_sqlerrm); END;",
        [
                affiliateNumber,
                depositIdentifier,
                depositType,
                depositAmount,
                depositCommunication,
                depositDate,
                criterium
        ])

println "Groovy return = ${returnCode}"
```

But I would like to have a nicer way to pass those SQL OUT parameters ...

PS: I'm working with groovy-2.4.13 and tried the Oracle jdk 9 AND 1.8.0_151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a procedure with a signature

```
 procedure proc_x (a number, b number, ret out number )
```

this works for me

```
def a = 100
def b = 50 
def res

db.call("""begin
 proc_x(${a},${b},${Sql.inout(Sql.INTEGER(res))});
end;""") {result -> println "result ${a} + ${b} = ${result}"}


result 100 + 50 = 150
```

**Alternative usage without inout**

```
db.call("""begin
 proc_x(${a},${b},${Sql.INTEGER});
end;""") {result -> println "result out ${a} + ${b} = ${result}"}
```

.

```
db.call("CALL proc_x(${a},${b},?)" , [Sql.INTEGER] ) 
    {result -> println "result out ${a} + ${b} = ${result}"}
```

Comment: This is very strage because with `Sql.inout` this works.. In one hand it can be logical if you want to retrieve the parameter return data but in other hand in SQL this paremeter is defined as `OUT` and not as `IN OUT`....

Comment: @GrechkaVassili good observation. I never thought about inout from this perspective. Anyway I added two more straightforward options that work for me in the same way (without *inout*)